# Page numbers in LLNCS style

Tags: latex

I'm using the LLNCS layout for a latex paper. The page numbers are suppressed by default. How can I turn them on for drafts?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I took a quick look at the .cls file for this layout. it calls all the page styles as "empty"

you may want to try

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

or

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

in your preamble. I didn't check to see if that worked, but the .cls loads a two sided article class...

Comment: You should add a note to say \usepackage{fancyhdr} as well.

Answer (score 20):

Using \pagestyle{fancy} only works if you also use the package fancyhdr, otherwise it won't compile. The simplest way to get page numbers is to use

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

but note that you will only see page numbers starting on the second page. Here's a complete sample document. Just add enough content to make two pages worth

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\title{Sample title}
\author{Some Author}
\maketitle

Content goes here.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you also want a page number on the first page you can use `\thispagestyle{...}` as follows:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}
Content
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. Without \thispagestyle{plain} after \maketitle the first page won't be showing the number.